# How do get CloudFront to follow a 302 redirect from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

When putting CloudFront in front of S3 bucket, I can get existing objects at the root level or even in subfolders to be served, **but any redirects won't be followed**. Instead, CF returns a 404.

I have a 302 redirect rule in S3 to point it to a lambda function which does on the fly image resizing on a 404. This works when I bypass CloudFront. The image is resized and served back to me, a copy is then put in S3 and any future queries will be a hit (200 okay).

I have read that CF will *not follow 301 and 307 redirects*, but it says nothing about 302.

My CF *Origin Domain Name* is my S3 static host URL, e.g. 
*my-bucket-name.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was still using the S3 
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com domain

I need to use the CF Domain name provided here

/console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront

format should be `<id>.cloudfront.net`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where did you need to change the domain name - in your Lambda function?

Comment: How did you do the 302 redirect? I am struggling with just that?